# Which random variables $X,Y$ are related by $Y=X^2$ operation?

Tags: probability, distributions, random-variable, teaching

For which  $X$ coming from some named distribution family, does distribution of $X^2$ also have a name?

Here are some examples I found, any others?

```
Rayleigh -> Exponential
Chi -> Chi Square
Normal -> Chi Square
Student-T -> F ratio distribution
Exponential -> Weibull
Wigner Semicircle->Marchenko Pastur
Cauchy -> Beta prime
Uniform -> Beta(1/2, 1)
Gamma -> Generalized Gamma
Bernoulli -> Bernoulli
```

<sup><sub>[notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-distribution-growth.nb)</sub></sup>

Comment: lookup $\chi^2$

Comment: I’m curious to know what the purpose of knowing this is.

Comment: @mhdadk for teaching/exposition

Comment: The square of a Beta variable rarely has a Beta distribution and the square of a Gamma variable never has a Gamma distribution, so your examples call into question what you are asking.  Could you clarify?  Btw, frequently when any family of distributions is extended to distributions of powers of the variable it is termed "generalized." Thus, for instance, the square of a Gamma variable has a generalized Gamma distribution, etc. Also, would you include discrete distributions? For instance, the square of a Bernoulli$(p)$ variable is a Bernoulli$(p)$ variable (trivially).

Comment: @whuber clarified the Beta and Gamma example.

Comment: Related question asked at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/287686/identifying-x2-relationships-between-random-variables.

Comment: Thank you.  But isn't this question a matter of surveying all the (developing) literature on the hundreds, if not thousands, of univariate distributions that have been studied and named?  Because that's not suitable for a thread here on CV, it's not on topic, but what might rescue it would be a clear description of what all the "named distribution families" are that you might be interested in.